# AudioKit - audio engine configuration changes periodically

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioengine, audiokit

I have an app that uses samplers to play loops. I am in the process of converting my app from using AVAudioEngine to AudioKit. My app now works well except for this: Approximately every 1-3 minutes, my app receives two .AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange notifications in a row. There is no apparent pattern to its repetition and this happens on both my iPhone 6s and new iPad.

Here is my init code for my "conductor" singleton:

```
init() {        
    //sampler array
    //sampler array is cycled through as user changes sounds
    samplerArray = [sampler0, sampler1, sampler2, sampler3]

    //start by loading samplers with default preset
    for sampler in samplerArray {
        //get the sampler preset
        let presetPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentSound, ofType: "aupreset")
        let presetURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: presetPath!)

        do {
            try sampler.samplerUnit.loadPreset(at: presetURL)
            print("rrob: loaded sample")
        } catch {
            print("rrob: failed to load sample")
        }
    }

    //signal chain
    samplerMixer = AKMixer(samplerArray)
    filter = AKMoogLadder(samplerMixer)
    reverb = AKCostelloReverb(filter)
    reverbMixer = AKDryWetMixer(filter, reverb, balance: 0.3)
    outputMixer = AKMixer(reverbMixer)

    AudioKit.output = outputMixer

    //AKSettings.enableRouteChangeHandling = false
    AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true

    do {
        try AKSettings.setSession(category: AKSettings.SessionCategory.playback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
    } catch {
        print("rrob: failed to set audio session")
    }

    //AudioBus recommended buffer length
    AKSettings.bufferLength = .medium

    AudioKit.start()

    print("rrob: did init autoEngine")

}
```

Any AudioKit experts have ideas for where I can start troubleshooting? Happy to provide more info. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that would be causing this.  I'd suspect faulty hardware, but you've checked on to different devices so its not that. What an odd problem.

Comment: Well, resetting my iPad seems to have fixed the problem there. Then adding: AKSettings.numberOfChannels = 2 before AudioKit.start() seems to have fixed it on my iPhone. Strange problem.